# Пустое сохранение в JSON на Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity3d

Добрый день и прошу простить, но... Что я, черт возьми, делаю не так?
Пытаюсь реализовать простой проектик с разными вариантами сохранениям (JSON, PlayerPrefs, JSON + PlayerPrefs), но с самого начало все идет не так как надо.
Почему файл JSON пуст? Если так и должно быть то не работает загрузка

SaveLoader

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

public class SaveLoad : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Model model;
    private string path; 

    void Start ()
    {
        path = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "Save.json");
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F5))
            JSONsave();
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F6))
            JSONload();
    }

    private void JSONsave()
    {
        model = GetComponent<Model>();
        Debug.Log("HP saver object - " + model.HP);
        Debug.Log("Saver path - " + path);
        var JSON = JsonUtility.ToJson(model, true);
        Debug.Log("Saver string - " + JSON);
        File.WriteAllText(path, JSON);
    } 

    private void JSONload()
    {
        model = JsonUtility.FromJson<Model>(File.ReadAllText(path));
        Debug.Log("HP load - " + model.HP);
    }
}
```

Скрипт который должен сохраниться

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[Serializable]
public class Model : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] public int HP { get; set; }

    void Start ()
    {
        HP = 3;
    }
}
```

> ArgumentException: Cannot deserialize JSON to new instances of type 'Model.'
>   UnityEngine.JsonUtility.FromJson (System.String json, System.Type type) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/JSONSerialize/Public/JsonUtility.bindings.cs:48)
>   UnityEngine.JsonUtility.FromJson[Model] (System.String json) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/JSONSerialize/Public/JsonUtility.bindings.cs:33)
>   SaveLoad.JSONload () (at Assets/Scripts/SaveLoad.cs:36)
>   SaveLoad.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/SaveLoad.cs:21)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А где сам JSON, а где данные из `File.ReadAllText(path)`? Нам гадать почему вы не можете это все сделать? А также прошу, нет, умоляю вас перенести весь код с картинок и написать его текстом!

Comment: Показали бы как сохраняете... 90% косяк там

Comment: @EvgeniyZ прошу прощения, второй раз пользуюсь данным ресурсом и впервые показываю здесь код (все таки я ещё слишком юн и неопытен)... Обычно все как-то в гугле находилось, а тут что-то даже не знаю... Да, я знаю что я не очень сообразителен, но прошу, проявите терпение :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы все делаете верно с сохранением в json, но проблема кроется в том, что нельзя сериализовать свойства. Об этом указано в [документации по SerializeField](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html).

То есть, если вы сделаете так:

```
[Serializable]
public class Model : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private int _hp;
public int HP 
{
     get { return _hp;} 
     set { _hp = value;} 
}

void Start ()
{
    HP = 3;
}
```

то, все должно работать нормально.
Чтобы избежать подобных проблем в будущем - проверяйте сериализацию в инспекторе. То есть JsonUtility будет сериализовать класс точно также, как вы будете видеть его в окне Inspector. А если не хотите, чтобы сериализуемое приватное поле было видно в инспекторе, используйте атрибут `[HideInInspector]`

Comment: Вы не представляете как я вам благодарен! 
Из-за своей лени, невнимательности и нежелания лезть в документацию я на этом уже успел ТЗ завалить (правда там было ещё FRP которое я так же не знаю, но встрял я тогда на Сериализации... Ещё раз спасибо :)

Comment: Рад помочь. Дьявол кроется в мелочах)